# TinyMCE - Hide Text

Tags: tinymce

I am trying to setup a "template" of sorts of use with TinyMCE.  One idea I had was to hide or lock certain elements from being edited in the graphic view, and only allow them to be displayed and change in the HTML view.

The idea was so that the general user would just open it in the graphic view, change their text, and be on their way.  Anything to idiot proof things in a way where the user doesn't have to worry about accidentally changing the wrong thing that throws off the entire page.

I know there are some implementations that show a flash object as a yellow box, that can't be changed .. that sort of idea.  Is there a built in way to do this, or would it have to be some type of extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TinyMCE doesn't have any way to do this natively, and it has actually come up before in my own work.

Your best solution, practically, is to not even show those parts that need to be read-only *outside of* your TinyMCE instance. So you could have, for example, a static header followed by an editor box, followed by a static footer. The header and footer are shown to the user only so they can visualize the completed document, but they will already understand they are not editable. You could even have multiple editable sections, and combine their contents before you send it to the server for retention. Then of course you'd want to split the information into sections when loading the page, but I think this combined work would be less than hacking TinyMCE to do what you're describing exactly.

Comment: I figured this was a long shot, but you have confirmed my findings that there is not an easy way to try to make this work